# How can I fix this legend labels issue in plotly (Python)?

Tags: python, plotly, legend, linechart, legend-properties

Heres the code for **Line Plot with column encoding color** from website: [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/).

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color='country')
fig.show()
```

My output legend label varies from the site please the below images :

Website Image result
[image: Website Image]

My Image Output[image]

**Could any one help me, to fix this legend label issue with equal sign and the get the desired output as the first image. At present it look weird for my original data as it has more than 10 categories for a column and facing this  legend problem is in each type of graph.**

Comment: Can you please mention the version of `plotly` that you are using? I am getting the expected results on running the same code snippet. I am using Version `5.1.0`.

Comment: @AnimikhAich the plotly version is 4.4.1 and I am running the code on Google Colab.

Comment: @AnimikhAich The issue is resolved now. Your version info fixed it. Thanks

Comment: @AnimikhAich feel free to add your comment as an answer — that way anyone with the same question can be directed to your answer. people often don't look through comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to version differences of `plotly`.

To fix the same, you can:

- Upgrade `plotly` on Google Colab or Jupyter Notebook: `!pip install --upgrade plotly`
- Upgrade `plotly` on your system or Terminal: `pip install --upgrade plotly`

The Version `5.1.0` supports the required configuration.

To Install a specific version of plotly, you can use the command: `pip install plotly==5.1.0`